# Trim just 1sec mp3 file by sox command

Tags: sox

I wanted create just 1sec mp3 file by sox command.
I published command below

```
sox input.mp3 output.mp3 trim 0 1
soxi output.mp3
```

The result is

```
Input File     : 'output.mp3'
Channels       : 2
Sample Rate    : 44100
Precision      : 16-bit
Duration       : 00:00:01.04 = 46040 samples = 78.2993 CDDA sectors
File Size      : 16.7k
Bit Rate       : 128k
Sample Encoding: MPEG audio (layer I, II or III)
```

I wanted to get 1.00 sec mp3 file, but 1.04 sec mp3 created.

I tried sox command option s(samples). but same result.

```
sox input.mp3 output.mp3 trim 0 44100s
```

It is not possible to trim 1.00sec mp3 file?

Answer (score 0):

I can do it. outputs wav file format.